# View [ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]

Tags: mysql, sql

Sobre *VIEW* em banco de dados...Qual é a diferença entre os três algorítimos ao se criar uma *VIEW* com `[ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]`? O que cada um faz?

Answer (score 1):

Para UNDEFINED, MySQL escolhe qual algoritmo usar.

Ele prefere MERGE sobre TempTable se possível, porque MERGE é geralmente mais eficiente e porque a VIEW não pode ser atualizável se uma tabela temporária é usada .

A razão para escolher TempTable explicitamente é que os bloqueios podem ser liberados em tabelas subjacentes após a tabela temporária foi criada e antes de ser usado para terminar o processamento da declaração.

Isso pode resultar em liberação mais rápida de bloqueio do que o algoritmo de fusão para que outros clientes que utilizam o ponto de vista não são bloqueados por tanto tempo.